# Cannot make metafields per variant visible in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I want to add a metafield for every variant in Shopify. My [website is this](https://yardigloo.com/). I tried everything it says in [this article](https://www.identixweb.com/an-ultimate-guide-to-shopify-variant-metafields-for-your-store/), but the metafield does't change when we select other variation, only after refresh. I guess it's something wrong with the code. Any solutions?

https://www.identixweb.com/an-ultimate-guide-to-shopify-variant-metafields-for-your-store/

Comment: Please share the code and not just links, thanks.

Comment: {% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id == variant.id %}
<strong>Only {{ variant.metafields.my_fields.quantity_by_color }} PCS are available in {{variant.title}}!</strong>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".no-js-hidden").on("click", function(){
var refreshint = setInterval(function(){
location.reload();
}, 1000);    });   });
</script>

Comment: Liquid is a server side language. To have a dynamic behaviour you need to add some js. I suggest you to add the metafield in the html (as `data-quantity`) for example and then use it with javascript.